# Clustering algorithm for obtaining equal sized clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pam

I am trying to form clusters around medoids using PAM algorithm in R. Is there anyway of fixing the cluster size for PAM (somewhat bruteforce the cluster size) ? Are there any other clustering algorithms that will provide equal sized clusters for medoids ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Duplicate to: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/clustering-procedure-where-each-cluster-has-an-equal-number-of-points

Comment: Special case of duplicate: [Optimal grouping/clustering of items in groups with minimum size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589168/optimal-grouping-clustering-of-items-in-groups-with-minimum-size)

Comment: Hi @Lawrence did you get any answer to this problem? I'm looking for an R implementation of such algorithm, but couldn't find any. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can **modify a clustering algorithm** to suit your needs.

You can follow this [Tutorial for Same-Size K-Means](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SameSizeKMeans), or simply use this algorithm from the `tutorial` package/module in ELKI (build the latest version from GitHub, because I just fixed a bug there - this will be included in ELKI 0.7.2).

Essentially, this algorithm performs a k-means style least-squares optimization, but all clusters must have the same size (if N/k is not integer, the cluster sizes may vary by 1).

If you go to above tutorial and scroll to the bottom, you can see example results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am working with a dissimilarity matrix (I do not have coordinates to be able to use kmeans). My data is in the form objects and a weight is attributes to each pair. That's why I am using PAM. I have however developed my own clustering algorithm appropriate to my problem. Will post it when I finish coding. Thanks again !

Comment: You can essentially follow the tutorial, but work with KMedoidsEM instead of KMeans. It's similar to k-means but uses the medoid like PAM. With above modifications, you will get a k-medoids that ensures clusters have the same size.